# How do I change an entity framework project to use Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-express, sql-server-2014

I am trying to debug a program using Entity Framework code first on my personal (work) computer.

We have recently had a domain migration, meaning that the user I log in as now is not the same that I used before. This caused me to loose access to the databases I had on the computer. To get around this, I have uninstalled everything to do with Microsoft SQL Server on the computer, and installed the latest version of Microsoft SQL Server, 2014 - 12.0.4213.0 . I then restored the database I need.

When I first tried to run the program, Visual Studio complained that the project is set up to use SQL Server Express, which was not installed. The recommended solution is to change the project to use SQL Server instead. To do this, I must click on "the database file" and follow the instructions. I have looked through the entire solution. There is a great many files, but I found no good candidate for "the database file."

It seems that my Google fu is not strong enough to find anything about this. So my question is: how do I change the project to use SQL Server?

I also have a second, related question. I tried to solve the problem by installing SQL Server Express. However, when I try to restore the database to this, no base appears in the drop down list. When I try to run the program now, I get another error:

> Unable to create the file 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Timelønsblanket.mdf' because it already exists.

I guess that this is also why I cannot restore the database. What I have found in websearches warns that I should not manually delete `.mdf` files.

Any advice on what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem. All that was needed was a correct connection string. No need to find a "database file".